# Hartshorne's Ex 1.7.7 generalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is inspired on Harshtorne's excercise 1.7.7, it asked to prove this

> Let $Y$ be a variety of dimension $r$ and degree $d>1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $P\in Y$ be a nonsingular point. We define $X$ to be the closure of the union of all lines $PQ$, where $Q\in Y$, $Q\neq P$. Then we have that $X$ is a variety of dimension $r+1$ and that deg $X < d$.

I was wondering, what happens if we have some point $P$ with multiplicity $m >1$ (hence singular), do we have some result like that one?

Thinking analogously on the non singular case, my guess is that we would have that the dimension of $X$ will be $md+1$ and deg $X < md$ but I'm not able to prove it. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: I think your general formula isn't true for the following "degenerate" case. Consider a curve (nodal or cuspidal cubic or something) in $\mathbb{P}^n$ that is contained in a copy of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (i.e. a "plane curve"). Even if you pick the singular point of $P$, all lines must still be contained in the plane and hence the dimension will be at most $2$ no matter the multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on Matt's comment, your guess for the dimension of $X$ isn't right. In fact, by thinking about a suitable rational map $Y \times \mathbf{A}^1 \dashrightarrow X$, it's not too hard to see that $\mathrm{dim} \ X=r+1$ unless $P$ is a *cone point* of $Y$, in which case $\mathrm{dim} \ X=r$.